# Devise Admin model - how to add another fields, such as admin's name and so on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

I use [Devise admin model](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role) and I would need to add to the model another fields, like admins name, age and so on.
Where to specify these information?

I've tried to add these fields to the form, but when the form was sent, these information were not saved to the database table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Rails? Post your database migrations that create and/or update the admin_users table.

Comment: if i get u well, i.e. add fields like admin name, age to the model, why dont you write a migration adding those fields to the model.
Eg. rails g migration add_fields_to_model name:string age:integer

Also when u say the fields are not sent, did u whitelist them as strong params in the controller of your model.